# spacemacs osx layer

Tags: spacemacs

I'm trying spacemacs for the first time.

Since I'm on mac, I'd like to change command key as Meta, so I put the following code, and restarted emacs.

It's not working as expected.

When I do `Command-x` it is recognized as `s-x` I think it is `hyper-x` (although I have not used `hyper` much)

```
(defun dotspacemacs/layers ()
  "Configuration Layers declaration.
You should not put any user code in this function besides modifying the variable
values."
  (setq-default
   ;; Base distribution to use. This is a layer contained in the directory
   ;; `+distribution'. For now available distributions are `spacemacs-base'
   ;; or `spacemacs'. (default 'spacemacs)
   dotspacemacs-distribution 'spacemacs
   ;; Lazy installation of layers (i.e. layers are installed only when a file
   ;; with a supported type is opened). Possible values are `all', `unused'
   ;; and `nil'. `unused' will lazy install only unused layers (i.e. layers
   ;; not listed in variable `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers'), `all' will
   ;; lazy install any layer that support lazy installation even the layers
   ;; listed in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers'. `nil' disable the lazy
   ;; installation feature and you have to explicitly list a layer in the
   ;; variable `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers' to install it.
   ;; (default 'unused)
   dotspacemacs-enable-lazy-installation 'unused
   ;; If non-nil then Spacemacs will ask for confirmation before installing
   ;; a layer lazily. (default t)
   dotspacemacs-ask-for-lazy-installation t
   ;; If non-nil layers with lazy install support are lazy installed.
   ;; List of additional paths where to look for configuration layers.
   ;; Paths must have a trailing slash (i.e. `~/.mycontribs/')
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layer-path '()
   ;; List of configuration layers to load.
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     javascript
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     ;; Example of useful layers you may want to use right away.
     ;; Uncomment some layer names and press <SPC f e R> (Vim style) or
     ;; <M-m f e R> (Emacs style) to install them.
     ;; ----------------------------------------------------------------
     helm
     ;; auto-completion
     ;; better-defaults
     emacs-lisp
     ;; git
     ;; markdown
     ;; org
     ;; (shell :variables
     ;;        shell-default-height 30
     ;;        shell-default-position 'bottom)
     ;; spell-checking
     ;; syntax-checking
     ;; version-control

     (osx :variables
          osx-command-as       'meta
          osx-option-as        'meta
          osx-control-as       'control
          osx-function-as      nil
          osx-right-command-as 'left
          osx-right-option-as  'left
          osx-right-control-as 'left
          osx-swap-option-and-command nil)
     )
   ;; List of additional packages that will be installed without being
   ;; wrapped in a layer. If you need some configuration for these
   ;; packages, then consider creating a layer. You can also put the
   ;; configuration in `dotspacemacs/user-config'.
   dotspacemacs-additional-packages '()
   ;; A list of packages that cannot be updated.
   dotspacemacs-frozen-packages '()
   ;; A list of packages that will not be installed and loaded.
   dotspacemacs-excluded-packages '()
   ;; Defines the behaviour of Spacemacs when installing packages.
   ;; Possible values are `used-only', `used-but-keep-unused' and `all'.
   ;; `used-only' installs only explicitly used packages and uninstall any
   ;; unused packages as well as their unused dependencies.
   ;; `used-but-keep-unused' installs only the used packages but won't uninstall
   ;; them if they become unused. `all' installs *all* packages supported by
   ;; Spacemacs and never uninstall them. (default is `used-only')


   dotspacemacs-install-packages 'used-only)

  )
```

Comment: What happens when you replace the variables ```osx-command-as```, ```osx-option-as```, and ```osx-control-as``` with ```osx-left-command-as```, ```osx-left-option-as```, and ```osx-left-control-as```, respectively? I'm not sure how much experience you have with Emacs, but ```M-x describe-key``` (or the binding ```C-h k```) will show you the modifier mapped to the key pressed immediately afterward. So you can press e.g. ```Command a``` and note the text displayed in the [echo area](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Echo-Area.html#Echo-Area). The letters ```C```, ```M```,

Comment: fwiw, I'm in the same boat: I want to swap option and meta. However, I don't want osx keybindings throughout, just to swap those two keys. This layer is not the right choice for this. I wish I knew what is.

Answer (score 1):

You're not giving enough information to help debug: from details of the errors you're seeing to what version of Spacemacs you have installed. I have just installed a clean Spacemacs repo (the `develop` branch), added `osx` layer to `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` (with no layer variables), and had no problems.

The `osx` layer maps Cmd key to Hyper since commit [2215ffe68](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/commit/2215ffe68d36c5a2f80b0830e2f7f19bb7803ce2) because of various possible issues when using Alt or Super. They also don't recommend mapping it to Meta -- see the commit message for details.

Also note that the layer maps most but not all the standard macOS key bindings: the one that I noticed right away was Cmd-o to open a file. I just bind it to `((kbd-mac-command "o") . counsel-find-file)` in my config.

I'd suggest you give it a another try by checking out the `develop` branch of Spacemacs, but with just `osx` with no layer vars in your `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`. Report here if you see any errors.